# paypal: mark payment as processed via REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We are taking payments via the PayPal rest API. Every so often we get an email asking us to mark the payment as processed (even if our product is a digital service/product that does not require shipping).

Is there a way to deal with this via the API? What we would ideally like is that marking the payment as processed straight after executing the payment via the API (as our product is digital and does not need to be shipped).

Answer (score 0):

we are also looking for an information like that...

so the "PayPal Support" told us to implement this feature, but we can not found any informations in one of this documentation, only this "FAQ" entry.

for me it looks like, there is no API or the API Doc is incomplete.

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-do-I-add-tracking-information-to-my-payment-or-mark-an-order-as-processed-FAQ3222